# Is Apache Shindig 100% compatible with iGoogle implementation

Tags: apache, comparison, compatibility, igoogle, apache-shindig

Is Apache Shindig 100% compatible with iGoogle implementation of gadgets.* API and gadget XML specs.

best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

iGoogle (and Orkut, and Wave, etc) all use Apache Shindig to power their gadget sites.

There are a number of iGoogle specific extensions that are not part of Shindig so it is not 100% compatible.  Also the default Shindig container implementation does not support UserPrefs very well.

However this will get better soon.  Google is contributing what they call the 'common-container' to Shindig, which will make it more compatible and capable.

Comment: When can we expect this new version ?

Comment: The common container is a work in progress, expect it in the 2.1.x timeframe when everything is converted over to it.